# Is .NET supporting changes on a running desktop app?

Tags: .net

I'm wondering if there is something like Hotswap/HotDelpoy/JRebel (known from Java World) in .NET Desktop Applications (no stateless webapps)?

As an example you change a functionality in the IDE while the Program is Running and the changes are instantly reflected in the running app

Do .NET Programmer need to restart the app on every change to validate it?

Comment: For the complexity involved in updating a running application - is it not sufficient to give the user a visual indication that an update is available and simply have them restart the application? A clickonce deployment makes this a very simple and feasible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you hit a break point you are free to modify the code.  When you continue the code will be re-compiled.

I believe that the marketing term for this is "Edit and Continue" (and of course only applies to Visual Studio).

Comment: This is only true for certain edits. Some do require you to stop and restart the application.

Comment: That's true, I just haven't hit that myself as I tend to only change minor things while debugging.

Comment: You can't use "Edit and Continue" feature for a web application which is hosted in IIS or Web Development Server.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the feature you are likely looking for is "Edit and Continue".  It was added in VS2005 and has been supported since, however there are some scenarios where it won't work:

- Can't use it to debug 64-bit applications
- Can't edit & continue with changes to classes that have generic parameters
- Can't edit & continue with changes to methods that have anonymous methods or lambda expressions within them
- Probably a couple other cases

Answer (score 0):

Look at the System.AddIn namespace.

Or, for updating an entire app, ClickOnce deployment.

Edit...

Hmm... re-reading and it sounds like you're talking about while still debugging.  In that case, it's called "Edit and Continue".

Comment: i'm not debugging;) just wondered if the .NET World have similar Problems as the Java Guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to a hotswap or upgrade if your desktop application sets up multiple application domains (see [`System.AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx)). Then each application domain can be hotswaped or upgraded without requiring a restart of your application. However, you will have to unload and load the `AppDomain` again.